# Group by number of instances of product sold descending and then order by string length of product name in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns: `product_id` and `product_name`. Each `product_id` is repeated multiple times and each occurrence equals one sale.

I want to count the number of times the `product_id`s occur and order them from the most sold to the least and then I want to order it by the length of the `product_name` which is a string.

Right now this is what I have now and I am not sure it is correct:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*), LEN(product_name) AS NameLength 
FROM table
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(product_id) DESC, LEN(product_name);
```

Comment: Why are you not sure it is correct?  Does the query return results?

Answer (score 1):

You can not add LEN(product_name) in the selection without adding the same in the GROUP BY part. You can try this following script which will first order the result by Most Order Count of a Product and then by length of product name if there more then one product available with the same count.

```
SELECT product_id,LEN(product_name), COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY product_id,LEN(product_name)
ORDER BY COUNT(product_id) DESC, LEN(product_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you want in the SELECT list the length of the `product_name` but the `product_name` itself, so you must `GROUP BY product_id, product_name` and `ORDER BY COUNT(product_id) DESC, LEN(product_name)`:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*), product_name
FROM tablename
GROUP BY product_id, product_name 
ORDER BY COUNT(product_id) DESC, LEN(product_name);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32199f3c7c5f5532872b60f01a23f8d2).